# reload with javascript/jquery and remove php post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, reload

when i reload a page with javascripts location.reload() all the $_POST data remains the same as before. Is there a possibility to reload the page without keeping the POST data?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace the location by itself using JS:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

This should not trigger the browser to post the data again.